# Birds of Paradise in vim - doesn't work

Tags: themes, vim

I want to add this theme [Birds of Paradise](https://github.com/kennethlove/Birds-of-Paradise-VIM-Theme) to vim.

I tried to it do with `sudo gedit birds_of_paradise.vim` in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors`. Then I tried  `colorscheme birds_of_paradise` in  `.vimrc` , but it didn't work. (I haven't received an error, but when I try to do `vim source.cpp` it doesn't change the color scheme.)

Please tell me if you have any idea about what's wrong.

Edit: [Here](http://pastebin.com/5QssW8ar) is my .vimrc, maybe here is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

- Copy the `birds_of_paradise.vim` file in `~/.vim/colors`. Make the directory first, if it does not exist.

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
cp birds_of_paradise.vim ~/.vim/colors
```

- Set `colorscheme birds_of_paradise` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Still doesn't work... same problem, it doesn't change anything.